# Invocar component dentro de outro component - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, componentes

Preciso chamar um component dentro de outro no blade em laravel.

Suponhamos que possuo o seguinte component

```
<x-component />
```

Então no arquivo de component eu declaro:

```
<div class="foo bar"> 
  <div class="bla blo">Titulo normal</div>
  <x-subcomponent prop1 prop2 />
  <div>testando</div>
</div>
```

Porém x-subcomponent não é renderizado enquanto que component é.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a diretiva [`@include`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews) para incluir um componente dentro de outro componente no Blade.

```html
<div class="foo bar"> 
  <div class="bla blo">Titulo normal</div>
  <!-- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews -->
  @include("components.seu-componente", ["prop1" => "foo", "prop2" => "bar"])
  <div>testando</div>
</div>
```